# inter-tenant collaboration with more than 2 Tenants

Tags: azure, synchronization, multi-tenant, onedrive, microsoft365

Is it possible, with a guest account that has permissions to access the m365 tenants of two different companies, to sync both companies' OneDrive files on a local computer at the same time?

I have an busines Premium Account and with this account I have access to 2 different companies. however, I dont want to login to the Sharepoints of these companies every single time, so I need these files synced to my local hardrive. is that possible ore are there limitations to do that?

I allready Synced the files from one company, when I wanted to sync the files of the other Company, I got an arrorr that onedrive currently was not able to sync these files.
I then downloaded the latest version of oneDrive and still got the same error. I now want to know if it is even possible, to do so.